# FreeRTOS Arduino MEGA 2560 vTaskDelay() not working

Tags: arduino, freertos

I have an Arduino MEGA 2560 running a FreeRTOS sketch using Arduino_FreeRtos. Everything appears to be working correctly except for vTaskDelay functions. Below is one of the areas I am having an issue.

```
    taskENTER_CRITICAL();
    MOTORS[5].motor(1, 120);
    MOTORS[6].motor(1, 127);
    taskEXIT_CRITICAL();
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(9000));
    taskENTER_CRITICAL();
    MOTORS[5].motor(1, 0);
    MOTORS[6].motor(1, 0);
    taskEXIT_CRITICAL();
```

The first task critical section starts moving my motor forward. There is supposed to be a 9 second delay and then the motor is supposed to stop in the second task critical section. What is actually happening is the motor moves forward for ~1 second and then stops.

I do have INCLUDE_vTaskDelay enabled in the FreeRTOSConfig.h file.
[image]

What else can I look at to try and find out why vTaskDelay is not working?

---

Below is the definition for the clock. Per comment that the clock may not be correct. I can't decipher if the clock is correct or not. Hopefully someone can point out if this setting may be causing the issue.
[image]

Comment: I suspect that you are not running at the clock frequency you expect.

Comment: @Realtime Rik: I added the definition for the clock. Do you see any issues with this definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The I think the problem is that 128000 >> (portUSE_WDTO + 11) is probably 0 (unless portUSE_WDTO is negative).
In order to get the correct timings you need to check that the tick rate is as expected (30ms). This is unlikely to be the case at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Since the frequency of AVR's watchdog oscillator is voltage- and temperature-dependent, it isn't a good idea to use `vTaskDelay` for precise timing intervals. Notice that it is especially unstable around 5V @ 25C, i.e. in most typical application.

> The frequency of the Watchdog Oscillator is voltage dependent as shown in “Typical Characteristics” on page 373.
> [image]

If you need a precision timing your options are:

1. Use a hardware AVR timer fed from the crystal oscillator,
2. Tweak the FreeRTOS code to switch the clock source from WDT to AVR hardware timer

In this regard, Arduino_FreeRTOS documentation mentions:

> The 8-bit AVR Timer0 has been added as an option for the experienced user. Please examine the source code to figure out how to use it. Reconfiguring Timer0 for FreeRTOS will break Arduino millis() and micros() though, as these functions rely on Timer0.